# Retrieving "businesses" with Google Maps API?

Tags: django, google-maps, geocoding, google-api

This is an example of a **[Business on Google Maps](http://maps.google.co.uk/maps/place?cid=10261706798760627533&q=Ministry%20of%20Sound,%20Camberwell,%20Greater%20London%20SE1%206,%20UK&hl=en&cd=1&cad=src:pplink&ei=IjNWS_ecOdm8jAelouCzAg&sig2=phN3gllKCW1KB5NruDqKLA)**

It has elements attached such as:

- **Reviews** from various sites (qype, viewlondon, etc...)
- **Details** provided by various sites
- **Photos** and **other** content

I don't know how to go on about retrieving such Business and associate any items generated on my website.

What I have implemented up to date is a system using **geocoding** (**geopy**) which once given an address, it gives back **Latitude** and **Longitude**, but such system **does not help me** with this dilemma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is this API:
http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/local.html

Also check this:
http://googleajaxsearchapi.blogspot.com/2007/06/local-search-control-for-maps-api.html

Comment: thanks alfatek! btw how would I go on about attaching items to the business though?

Answer (score 1):

By writing a relay server script you could do things like [this](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_egeohotels.htm), which obtains most of that information with a different layout. I don't know if it's legal to do that.