# Get a list of businesses from a public site like Google, Bing Maps or yellow pages

Tags: maps, localized

I would like to know is there a way to get a list of all businesses using an zip-code.

edit:
I found this another question on SO
[Retrieving "businesses" with Google Maps API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097792/retrieving-businesses-with-google-maps-api)
But this is not exactly I wanted.

Thanks,
Gokul

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://compass.webservius.com - it can do exactly what you require